# Jquery slider on Rails

Tags: jquery, css, sass, coffeescript, slim

Help me. I made a slider on the main page. On the screenshot it is on the right. Everything seems to be good. ut when I scale the page, the slider enlarges and climbs up the text. How do I fix this? I use jquery sliders. Thanks.

**SLIM**

```
    .bg-image-top

      .container
        .text-container
          h1 = t '.h1_html'
          p = t '.text_top_html'
          p = t '.text_top2_html'
          .buttons
            = link_to t('.link_top_black'), want_to_be_member_path, class: 'btn-red'
            = link_to t('.link_top_red'), new_inquiry_path, class: 'btn-transparent'

      .bg-image-right   
        .container

                    #slideshow.sliders
                      .active-slide.slide
                         img[src="images/slider_images/CAIM na MSV 1.jpg"]
                      .slide
                         img[src="images/slider_images/Karаsek Kulhаnek.jpg"]
                      .slide
                         img[src="images/slider_images/DSC02131.JPG"]
                      .slide
                         img[src="images/slider_images/20170317_ZER_t_pastrnak_037.jpg"]


- if @featured
  .bg-image-middle
    .container style="background-image: url(#{attachment_url @featured.galleries.first, :file})"
      .row
        .text-container
          h3.highlighted
            = t '.middle_highlight'
          h2
            = @featured.name
          p
            == @featured.perex
          = link_to t('.middle_red_button'), (locked?(@featured) ? articles_path : @featured), class: 'btn-red'

        .btn-container
          = link_to about_path(anchor: t('anchor_pribehy_manageru')), class: 'btn-transparent'
            = t '.middle_gray_button'
            i.fc-arrow-right.icon-right
```

**SASS**

```
.bg-image-top
  background: image-url('') no-repeat right -50px bottom
  border-bottom: 1px solid $gray
  padding: 25px 0 130px
  @media(min-width: 1400px)
    background-position: right 17% bottom
  +render-to(md)
    background-position: right -150px bottom
  +render-to(sm)
    background-position: right -230px bottom
  +render-to(xs, ms)
    background: transparent
    padding: 30px 0

  .bg-image-right
    float: right
    position: sticky
    margin-top: -439px
    margin-right: -265px

    .sliders
      position: absolute
      overflow: hidden 
      box-sizing: border-box
      height: 570px
      width: 70%
      margin:auto
      z-index: 0

    .slide 
      height: inherit
      width: 100%
    .slide img 
      width: 100%
      height: 100%

  .text-container
    max-width: 600px
    margin-left: -25px
    h1
      color: $black-bright
      font-weight: 300
      font-size: 60px
      margin-top: 21px
      +render-to(xs)
        font-size: 40px
      strong
        color: $red
        font-weight: 700
    p
      font-size: 15px
    .buttons
      padding-top: 20px
      a
        margin-right: 20px
        padding: 18px 30px
        +render-to(xs, ms)
          margin-right: 0
          padding: 16px 20px
          width: 100%
          + a
            margin-top: 20px
```

**Coffee**

```
$(document).ready ->
 $('#slideshow').sliders interval: 3000
 return
```

Result when the page is scaled:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slDL2.jpg)

Comment: Looks to me like it's the `width: 70%`. You'll probably need to post a bit more Slim / Sass before people can answer fully - but I'd imagine the left hand container is a fixed width while your slider uses the percentage.

Comment: I made a fixed width and still also(